# How to get the SQL structure of specific table using Django?

Tags: mysql, sql, django

```
class Table1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Table2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    table1 = models.ManyToManyField(Table1)
```

Ex:

```
python manage.py sqlall app
```

The above command will give the SQL structure of all the tables in a specific application.

So, my question is,

How do I get the SQL structure of a specific table in the application? Suppose, if the table has Many To Many Field then How the SQL structure will be?

Comment: I think you have answered your own question. The SQL for a single table may not be meaningful on it's own

Comment: @FeLiX StEpHeN AFAIK, In Django there isn't an option to generate SQL structure of a single model of an application(unless the application has only one model in it :) ), but for all the models in the application.